# RapidGator Curl POST Data from Bash Issue

Tags: bash, api

The form is like from here( https://rapidgator.net/article/api/file#upload)

```
form method="post" action="http://pr3.rapidgator.net/?r=upload/api&uuid=0la4fzVZUMUulOliVcleXY0Kn9nmJGAy&sid=6eo5bhrslh3lggb8kmu8lgk781" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
</form
```

Everytime the action changes.

I have written something like-

```
FileResponse=$(curl '-X POST -d @'"$FullFileName"' '"$URL")
echo $FileResponse
```

where $FullFileName is for name and $URL is for action.

I have got the following response-

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your single and double quotes, `'-X POST -d @'"$FullFileName"' '"$URL"` is understood as one single parameter.

Each parameter must be quoted separately:

```
FileResponse=$(curl "-X" "POST" "-d" "@$FullFileName" "$URL")
```

Or just:

```
FileResponse=$(curl -X POST -d @"$FullFileName" "$URL")
```

Comment: Its not helping. Here is my repo- https://github.com/observo/Bash/blob/master/UploadFinal.sh